# Full Screen Call Push Notification - iOS

Tags: swift, ios10, sinch

I would like to implement a full screen push notification in iOS

(Something like WhatsApp's when a user calls another user in iOS)

Currently I notification that pops up on the top toolbar, its small and can be swiped. I would rather have it where the whole screen is taken over by the call screen and can be answered or declined.

Do I have to use PushKit from apple or does the SinchSDK (SinchRTC) already include this?

Answer (score 2):

That feature is included in apples CallKit, not pushkit.

Sinch support push kit (voipPushes) and we are 
working on callkit, but right now we don't support it at all even if you roll it yourself.

Comment: Approximately how long will it take for you guys to add support for this feature? How about a pre-release beta version?

Comment: Is it still same? We really want it)